# Pager controls are hidden in ABP user admin list

Tags: identity, hidden, abp, pager

The Administration > Identity Management > Users page only shows the first 10 users in the list.  The pager control exists in the DOM but it's hidden.  Is there any way to unhide the pager?

[image: hidden pager control]
[image: dom elements]

This seems to be due to the maxResultCount that's sent in the request.  Is there any way to override that without implementing a custom version of the User Management page?
[image]

This app is just using the default identity module. I'm hoping there's some simple way to fix this without using a custom users page.

Comment: Are you sure there are more than 10 users in the database? The list service comes with a default page of 10 and in the lower left corner it says the total is 10. That's why the paginator does not show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 10 users in total, when you add a new user, it should appear on your page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IiI7.png)

Comment: Yes, that's a good question.  There are 19 users in the database, but the query to get the list of users specifies a maxResultCount of 10, and I don't see anything in the network console that gets the total number of users.

Comment: Can you tell me which version and user interface you are using in abp so I can test the problem?

Comment: This is version 5.2.1 of abp, and the application UI is in Angular.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be due to the maxResultCount that's sent in the request.  Is there any way to override that without implementing a custom version of the User Management page?

Comment: Hello, I have examined it but there does not seem to be a problem with maxResultCount. Can you create a project again in the same version and try to add more than 10 users? I could not reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: Hi onurpicakci, I think my problem was that we had overridden the method to retrieve the list of users and were limiting the returned resultset to the default maxResultCount, which fooled the client side pager control into thinking there were only 10 users in the list.  Returning the full list of users allows the client side pager to work properly and show the paging controls.  Thank you for looking into this issue.